# split polygon lines or remove neighboring line (calculate distance between two points in polygon)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

Please sorry me for lot of questions!
But..my head explodes

I have polygon: 
[image: I have polygon like this]

I want to "split" him outer points  to left and right parts (or full remove one part)
Like that:
[image: Like this]

This is necessary me to control current GPS device position on the waypoint and detect direction of movement (run to end, run to begin or out from route)

Of course to detect direction i can find nearest point in route and detect position..but not always GPS position have high accuracy, point from GPS can jumping like that:
[image: Jumping]
 And i am unable detect direction on movement based on point enumeration because neighbour edge giving error when GPS point jumping.

```
   p0-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5-p6 
  (  [begin <- -> end ]   )
    p12 p11 p10 p9 p8 p7
```

May someone know the algorithm to split Polygon in two parts

or Algorithm for converting polygon into one linear line without neighbouring line
(Roughly speaking the boost::geometry::buffer working to backward)

**Simply put: I want to calculate distance between two points inside Polygon relative with polygon area**

[image: One case]

and

[image: two case]

Please sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you make a much simple example with exact expected outputs? I don't understand the pictures at all.

Comment: Hello! Thank for you reply! I want to calculate distance between two points inside Polygon _relative_ with polygon area, i  added new pictures in question.